# OLE DB access from Visual Studio 2019 error

Tags: winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, oledb

I try to access an OLE database in order to use it in a Windows Forms .NET Core Application in Visual Studio 2019 and I obtain the next error:

> System.Data.OleDb is not supported on this platform.

Comment: What is a *.NET Core Application*, in practice? What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: If you're actually building a WinForms app that targets .NET Core (3.0, 3.1), then I suggest you don't do that. If you cannot update to VS 2022, then at least target .NET 5, or step back, to .NET Framework 4.8. You can use `System.Data.OleDb` in both

Comment: Do you have reference to jimi's suggestion. Have you updated on this issue?

Comment: I have tried to target .NET 5 but it says that my OLE DB 7.0.0 cannot run with that version of .NET. I cannot find which OLE DB version is compatible with that.

Comment: I have run the same program on VS 2022 and it worked (with .Net 6.0). Thank you for the idea!

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT, I have tried something, but I don't know if it was answer marking. It is the first question that I ask on this platform. Is it alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says a winforms program targeting .NET 5 , OLE DB 7.0.0 cannot run on that version of .NET .

The solution is: the same program target .Net 6.0 works perfectly in VS2022.